# Cannot create a DbSet for 'DocumentChecklistItem' because this type is not included in the model for the context

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm getting the above mentioned error in my code.
Just to be clear from the very beginning, the code works, I have everything initialzed in DbContext correctly, running .NET Core 2.1. How I know that it works? Well because it's running correctly on the production server, 3 test servers, my 2 laptops and even my colleagues didn't encounter this bug.

I just can't seem to figure out where the hell is a difference between my desktop and two laptops where it works, as I've already tried even to reinstall windows on my desktop and even that didn't help.

Any ideas what can be wrong on my PC?
Have anyone encounter a similar problem?

Thanks! Much appreciated for all tips on how to fix this.

EDIT:

[image: DbContext]

[image: error]

Another weird thing is it happens only on this model. No idea why...

Comment: So, to be clear, `DocumentChecklistItem` is part of EF's class model as far as you're concerned, but EF can't seem to find it when running on your machine?

Comment: Yes, it's super super weird how it behaves. I've tried going back to older branch where I'm 100% sure it worked, but I'm getting the same result, so either I'm missing something installed which I'm 99.9% sure I'm not or it's something machine related.